# SCCM - Unable to push Windows Updates to Clients

Tags: windows-10, sccm, windows-update, system-center

After approving updates from WSUS then approving updates on SCCM we are getting an error saying "Download error - 0x80d02002" when a client goes to download an update from Windows Update. Any suggestions on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a firm answer but I can give you some information that might be helpful. 0x80d02002 is "DO_E_DOWNLOAD_NO_PROGRESS" -- it means that the client's download seemed to start all right, but then several minutes went by without receiving any data from the server.

One possible cause: Are you using express updates? Express updates reduce the amount of data being downloaded by each client computer, but at the expense of a lot more network round trips (clients making multiple small requests instead of one large one) and client-side CPU and disk usage (the client has to do a lot of file parsing to figure out exactly what parts of the express update packages it needs to download). Since nothing is being downloaded while the client is doing these computations, I have seen some cases where the computation cycle took so long that it triggered the download timeout.

If your WSUS/SCCM server is on the same intranet as your clients (meaning that bandwidth between the server and the clients is free and relatively unconstrained), I would suggest turning off express installation in the SCCM settings and seeing if that impacts your results.

Comment: Thanks, I am resyncing the updates now. Will update once I try again.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried what you suggested and updates still get hung up at the downloading stage :/ . Any further suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Very sorry!